# Ubuntu NTFS not write permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, permissions, ntfs

I have inside my system a m.2 samsung evo 970 formatted to NTFS. 3 weeks ago it was perfectly running with write permissions and everything no problem at all in Ubuntu 18.04. Then I upgraded to 19.10 it is mounted the partition without writing permissions. I juts can read but not create directories or copy files.

I went to disks GUI in Ubuntu and I added the “rw” as you can see in photo:

[Link to photo](https://ibb.co/7ScbtHX)

However not work, is mounted only as read only.

How can ali enable writing permissions to the partition again?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this page https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157165/cant-write-to-mounted-ext4-hard-drive-in-ubuntu-18-04 It might help you.

Comment: I tried to add the chown command and I have: chown: “changing ownership of Read-only file system“. Don’t do because it detects a read only volume. The problem is the “DISKS” GUI in Ubuntu it mounts as read only no matter if I have “rw”l Shat could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed disabling hibernation in windows and also write cache in the device and done. Linux. lungs perfectly with reading write permissions.

Thank you anyway